# Use dependency injection BuildUp after Server.Transfer in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have automated setup of Dependency Injection for an ASP.NET Web Forms application. I use Unity and have services build up on page request using `[Dependency]` attribute.

Having solution with `UnityHttpModule` like from [the example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664534(v=pandp.50).aspx) works well but when using `Server.Transfer()` dependencies are not build up for target page. 
Lifecycle events [are not executed again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11194147/469961) and it seems there is not much more to try but to use `BuildUp` on [base page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4028186/469961).

Is there a *recommended* way of handling this?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Try create injections using page factories.

http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/asp-net-web-forms-extensibility-handler-factories